# how to use javascript replace with variable pattern

Tags: javascript

i have an arithmetic expression which can have a number in American number word ( like 1000100 can be written as one million one thousand. I need to identify such patterns in a expression and convert them to their respective numeric equivalent.

I am using below code.

```
var patternToExtractOperand = '\+|-|\*|\/|%\sof|%|\(|\)';
expr = expr.replace(/patternToExtractOperand(.+?)patternToExtractOperand/g,word2number($1));
```

word2number is a function which convert word representation of any number till (10^68) into its respective number equivalent and patternToExtractOperand is the list prepared using supported patterns.

What should be the correct way to write above piece of code?
or 
how to use javascript replace with variable pattern?

Comment: You can use the `RegExp` constructor. Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

**Example:**

```
var patternToExtractOperand = "\\s*([A-Za-z]+)(\\d*)";
var regExp = new RegExp(patternToExtractOperand, "g");
console.log("   Welcome123 Welcome321".replace(regExp, function() {
        console.log(arguments);
        return arguments[1];
    }));
```

**Output**

```
{ '0': '   Welcome123',
  '1': 'Welcome',
  '2': '123',
  '3': 0,
  '4': '   Welcome123 Welcome321' }
{ '0': ' Welcome321',
  '1': 'Welcome',
  '2': '321',
  '3': 13,
  '4': '   Welcome123 Welcome321' }
WelcomeWelcome
```

**Explanation**

Whenever there is a match, function specified as `replace`'s second argument is called with the entire string matched and the groups matched (the string matched which is inside the brackets in the regular expression) and the first index where the match was found and then the actual string on which the search was performed.

So, in your case, you might want to change the function being passed to `replace` as follows.

```
result = stringToBeSearched.replace(regExp, function(entireMatch, firstMatchedGroup, secondMatchedGroup) {
        return word2number(secondMatchedGroup);
    });
```

and the `regExp` would be constructed like this

```
var patternToExtractOperand = "\\+|-|\\*|\\/|%\\sof|%|\\(|\\)";
var regExp = new RegExp(patternToExtractOperand + '(.+?)' + patternToExtractOperand, "g");
```